# Adding a timer in a C++ loop

Tags: c++

I found some simple Pi calculation programs written in C++. My knowledge of C++ isn't that good(none to be exact), but how do i go about implementing a timer to tell me how long it took for the program to calculate the Pi number?

Like: Pi calculation finished in X seconds or minutes or hours etc.

Comment: This highly depends on your development platform. Are you on Windows? POSIX system? Are you using any frameworks like Qt?

Comment: If you are using linux you can use `time` program. `time program_name` will show how much time takes your program execution.

Comment: If your algorithm finishes quickly* it can be a good idea to run it many times (thousands) in a loop and then calculate an average to get a more accurate measurement.

Comment: if you are using unix-like system, try `/usr/bin/time your_app`, could be quite useful. Do NOT use `time` in your shell because they sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   clock_t start = clock();
   /* Code you want timed here */
   printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Comment: +1, although I would rather use `<ctime>` and `<cstdio>` or better `<iostream>` otherwise, this is a pure C answer

Comment: Yea, and either this snippet is in function scope and so the usage of `#include` here is weird, or it's in global scope and the expressions are not in a valid place. Have edited to wrap code in `int main()`, include C++ headers and did the evil `using namespace std` (as opposed to the more intrusive alternatives) to bring the time stuff into scope; hope you don't mind, as the changes aren't crucial to the point you are making in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
class CBenchmark
{
    public:
        CBenchmark(void) throw() :
            m_startTime(0),m_finalTime(0)
    {}

        void start(void) throw()
        {
            m_startTime=getTime();
            return;
        }

        void stop(void) throw()
        {
            m_finalTime=getTime();
            return;
        }

        size_t elapsedTime(void) throw()
        {
            return m_finalTime-m_startTime;
        }
    protected:
        size_t getTime(void) throw()
        {
            timeval tp;
            gettimeofday(&tp,NULL);
            return tp.tv_sec*1e6+tp.tv_usec;
        }

        size_t m_startTime;
        size_t m_finalTime;
};
```

Comment: Where did the OP specify a POSIX-like system?